# Is Krampus real?

Tags: bavaria, christmas, folklore

By which I mean, is the whole krampus thing a real tradition or is it a fake tradition that someone just made up.
I have a degree in history, my wife studied folklore extensively in college. I read constantly. I've been off-season Christmas shopping in Bavaria! Given these facts, and that Krampus is very much aligned with my sense of humor/ethos/etc I feel like I really should have heard of Krampus before about five years ago, which is when it seemed to come to mainstream attention.

I somewhat reject the idea that I've shifted into a parallel dimension, so what's the gag? Why is Krampus everywhere now but was seemingly unmentioned before a few years ago?

Comment: Quite recent thing in the US, according to Wikipedia: [Krampus in North American popular culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krampus_in_North_American_popular_culture), but not in Central Europe.

Comment: *The history of the [Krampus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krampus) figure has been theorized as stretching back to Pre-Christian Alpine traditions. In a brief article discussing the figure, published in 1958, Maurice Bruce wrote: "There seems to be little doubt as to his true identity for, in no other form is the full regalia of the Horned God of the Witches so well preserved."*